# Good design DDD and IoC, how to inject an IRepository into model

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, inversion-of-control

I have a complex entity (`Message`) that has quite a hefty constructor (13 parameters), some of these parameters are in turn entities (`Verb`).

There are a number of things I need a repository of another Entity for (e.g. for some defaults).

What is a good way of using IoC and keeping the code clean / best practice?

Simplified code (I'd put the default verb list as a static object constructed by the static constructor personally, its the simplest if naff example of why my Message entity needs some sort of IRepositry).

```
private static IVerbRepository verbRepository;

static Message()
{
    using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
    {
        verbRepository = kernel.Get<IVerbRepository>();
    }
}

public Message(int id, string precis,
    DateTime created, DateTime validTo,
    PriorityType priority, Source source, SID createdBy,
    string content = null, string helpText = null,
    DateTime? validFrom = null, bool emailOnExpiry = false,
    IEnumerable<SID> targetUsers = null,
    IOrderedEnumerable<MessageVerb> verbs = null) : base(id)
{
    Verbs = verbs ??
            new List<MessageVerb>
            {
                new MessageVerb(
                verbRepository.GetByName("Acknowledge"), true,
                string.Empty)
            }.OrderBy(x => x.IsDefault);

    Precis = precis;
    Created = created;
    ValidTo = validTo;
    Priority = priority;
    Source = source;
    CreatedBy = createdBy;
    Content = content;
    HelpText = helpText;
    ValidFrom = validFrom;
    EmailOnExpiry = emailOnExpiry;
    TargetUsers = targetUsers;
}
```

The common practice seems to be to add an additional parameter to the constructor.  I don't get how this is better?  It means everytime you want to create a message, you need to write code to retrieve the repository.  Assumning you wrap this around in a Factory, it doesn't make sense to allow (logically if not actually) have different repositories for message entites?

**Edit 1**

Based on the first solutions the code would like this,

```
public Message(IVerbRepository verbRepository ...) {  }
```

Elsewhere in the same domain assembly

```
public MessageService
{
    private IVerbRepository VerbRepository {get; set;}
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<MessageVerb> DefaultVerb {get;}
}
```

Much higher up outside of my DDD (let's say my web services that accept creations of messages)

```
public class MessageWebService
{
    private static IVerbRepository _verbRepository;

    public void AddMessage(some parameters)
    {
        var message = new Message(_verbRepository, ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just because your constructor already has too many arguments doesn't mean constructor injection is bad. Anyway, why don't you use setter (property) injection ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There're two flavors of IoC: *Service Locator*, which you're using, and *Dependency Injection*, which you're asking about.

As of now, Service Locator is considered a kind of anti-pattern, because it introduces implicit dependencies (dependencies you can't figure out by looking at class's public interface) and makes testing harder.

Dependency Injection, on the other hand, does not have these problems, but tends to be more verbose in class declaration.

Now, regarding your question.

> I don't get how this is better?

It is explicit. You can see that your class depends on this or that service. BTW, *your* class doesn't, it only uses verb repository for locating default verb (which can be easily moved outside of class).

> Assumning you wrap this around in a Factory, it doesn't make sense to allow (logically if not actually) have different repositories for message entites?

It does when you think of testing. You should be easily able to substitute any service your CUT is depending on with testable implementation (stub).

Comment: updated my solution based on your suggestion.  Is that more like what you're suggesting?

Comment: @MAfifi What I would really try to do here is to totally remove dependency on `IVerbRepository` from `Message`. But there's still one point to make: when you go for DI, you go for it all the way, which means that your `MessageWebService` should also accept `IVerbRepository` from outside (and there's no point making `_verbRepository` static for the same reasons).

Comment: Sorry I thought I did, I meant to move the IVerbRepository into my MessageService.  Constructors of Message can grab the DefaultVerb attribute from my MessageService.  Can you elaborate then where is the right place to actually populate my IVerbRepository?  At some point _something_ has to pass in an IVerbRepository to my constructor.  Are you thinking a kernerl.Get<MessageWebService>() In that case, how would IIS know it needs to instantiate my webservice as such rather than call the parameterless constructor?

Comment: @MAfifi That's where dependency containers and service factories come in. Dependency containers resolve your dependency graphs for you, so you just have to wire those calls into appropriate places. Most modern frameworks have extension points; WCF, for example, has `IInstanceProvider` (I could give you an example implementation).

Comment: Seriously. You for got the most important thing: DDD models should be persistent ignorant. They should not use the repositories.

Comment: @jgauffin Item the first: repository does not necessary mean persistence. Item the second: while models should be persistence-ignorant, which means that they do not contain persistence-related code, they can use repositories, because there's no other way for them to get the data they need. They should possibly avoid calls that invoke persisting and defer that to UoW, but that's another point.

Answer (score 2):

Domain models should not be aware of the data source = don't use repositories in them. You probably need a service class which can implement the required business rules (services can use repositories).

It also seems like your model is too fat. Can't you break it into smaller pieces and use composition instead?

The constructor should only take required information as arguments. It's used to indicate just that. Everything else can be set using property setters or methods. I tend to favor private setters and public methods, but it requires that you use task based UI instead of crud (imho CRUD isn't a good fit for DDD either way)

Comment: It is a "slim" constructor.  Most of the objects as you can see are null by default (meaning you don't have to pass them in) with only the required properties set to make the entity valid.

Comment: Remove all constructor parameters which has default values. The only reason to have them is if the model is immutable.